# Save a Dynamic page from a URL using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic

how to get renderd data of a dynamic web page in Asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

you can use
HTML agility pack to get rendered data

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Example:-

[How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)